# Unable to boot Ubuntu 13.10 after install on acer desktop

Tags: installation, boot, partitioning

After install and restart I get an error screen saying "Reboot and Select proper Boot Device or Insert Boot Media in selected device and press a key"

This is an Ubuntu only boot.

When I first installed over Win 8.1 Ubuntu worked fine until I updated, now it seems after several installs that even just the 13.10 with no update is causing the same screen to show.

I've booted into Ubuntu to try and change the boot partition to be the first however there is a 500mb fat32 partition in front of it that I can't seem to remove or move.

I am also running Ubuntu 13.10 on my acer laptop which has been updated and working fine. Both installs were done from the same DVD.

I am believe it is the partition causing the problem but I have no clue how to change it.

Comment: Sounds like you have UEFI and a UEFI (500mb FAT32) partition. This is needed for the UEFI (what used to be the BIOS) work. Try `boot-repair` from the Live DVD. Follow the second answer to this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows

Comment: If Boot Repair doesn't work, post the URL that it provides. This will give us more detailed information about your system, which may be important in diagnosing and fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution has been tested just for an Ubuntu only boot system, and it works fine.

Here is the steps:

1. Insert the Ubuntu DVD, and choose "Try Ubuntu".
2. On live desktop run `Gparted`, and create a partition in an unallocated space, it's size should be more than 1 MB (make it 50 MB, and stay safe), and format it to `fat32`, then from "Edit" menu click "Apply all operations". Right click on this partition again and from "Manage flag" select "Boot".
3. Start the installation when you ready, and from "Installation Type" window choose "Something else", which will provide you with the partition table so you can change what you want.
4. Now, you will need three partitions,first one is the main partition you will install Ubuntu on it. It should be set to `ext4` and the "mount point" is set to `/`
   the second partition of course is the swap partition. You can set it during the creation or from "Installation Type" window.
5. The third partition is that you have created in (2). It will appear in partition table with type (efi). Choose this partition from "Device for boot loader installation" drop down menu.

Complete the installation process, and reboot.This procedure solved my "Reboot" message problem,and it should work fine for you too if there are no other problems.